# I'm having more eye rigging problems!

Tags: rigging

So I added a copy rotation constraint to the eyeballs on my character (yes this is the same one from my last two questions) so his eyes could track to the head bone properly, which they do in its local y and z axes, but not in its local x.  Furthermore, when I use the tracking targets (cubes) to aim where he's looking while his head is tilted quizzically sideways (tilted in world y axis), sometimes his eyes snap their orientation so he's looking at the back of his skull. Probably has something to do with the way the copy rotation constraint targeting his head bone interacts with the track to constraint targeting his eye pointers.  I have the file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Zkxb4zPn

Comment: Without looking at your file, why do you use a copy rotation constraint? Eyes usually are rigged using some form of track to.

Comment: Yes, the eyes track to a pair of empties floating in front of them, but I used the copy rotation constraint to make them still accurately match the rotation of the head bone to which the empties they were parented to were parented.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea, try parenting them to the head bone.